# Error using zonal statistic

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I'm using **2.8.1 QGIS** version (Wien) and I have a raster layer with FWI values and a vector with district polygons.

What I want is to calculate the mean pixel FWI value per district.

I know the Zonal Statistics funtion, but when I use her appears this error:

```
"Algorithm Zonal Statistics starting...
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exportToWkt' See log for more details".
```

I don´t know what could be the problem. I'm using the same CRS layers.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to several reasons. Have you checked the raw raster data including the NoData value using python? If not I can share a script with you to read the raster data but I am not sure whether you are comfortable with Python

Comment: alternatively you can share the two datasets if they're not too big